# sapui5 what are the differences between XML Model and JSON Model

Tags: sapui5

Currently in all of my projects im using [JSON Model](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel) for all client side manipulations. But `XML Model` also do the same. 
Can someone help me the exact differences between [XML Model](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel/overview)
 and `JSON Model`. And why developers are preferring `JSON Model` over `XML Model`??

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to use JSON in JavaScript, as it is derived from JavaScript.

Some JSON benefits:

- less verbose
- easier to read and write
- easily accessible with `JSON.parse()` function. XML parsing is inherently more work in JavaScript (`XMLModel` would be doing the work, but it is still more work being done).

Some XML benefits:

- schema support
- comment support

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.
In which kind of scenarios we need to go for XML Models??

Comment: I would only use an `XMLModel` when my data source supports neither OData nor JSON.